# Displaying conditional Fields in HTML&JS twice

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a list of many elements. When i have click a button I want to display next list. Until here, it's all good. When i have repeat this procedure for the newly opened list, the code didn't work. Why?

```js
//here open the first list

$("#product").change(function() { //product is id from first list
  var selected = $("#product").val();
  $('p').hide(); //p represents Paragraph. 
  $('#' + selected).show();

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').hide();
});

//here, i want to repeat same code for next list, but didn t work...

$("#1").change(function() { //1 is id from second list
  var selected = $("#1").val();
  $('p').hide(); //p represents Paragraph. 
  $('#' + selected).show();

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').hide(); //p represents Paragraph. 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="product" name="faculty" required="">
  <option value="">-- Choose--</option>

  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<p id="1">
  <select id="1" name="domeniul_mate_info" required="">

    <option value="">-- Choose--</option>
    <option value="info">Info</option>
    <option value="math">Math</option>

  </select>

</p>

<p id="info">
  <select name="info" required="">

    <option value="">-- Choose--</option>
    <option value="info1">info1</option>
    <option value="info2">info2</option>

  </select>

</p>
```

Comment: You have duplicate ID=1 Change to `<p id="p1">` and <select id="s1"  and change the values of the selects to match P or Select

Comment: Voting to close since the issue is _caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: Alternatively remove the id from the select and do `$("#1 select").on("change",function() { 
  var selected = $(this).val();
  $('p').hide(); 
  $('#' + selected).show();
});
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is you are using duplicate selector id 1 for both

element and  element. You can only use unique selector identifier. I have updated your code, please find code below and let me know if any issue.

```js
const product = [1, 2, 3];
const productDropDown1Relation = {
  1: ['info', 'math'],
  2: ['history', 'geography'],
  3: ['science', 'sport'],
}
const dropDown1DropDown2Relation = {
  info: ['info1', 'info2'],
  math: ['math1', 'math2'],
  history: ['history1', 'history2'],
  geography: ['geography1', 'geography2'],
  science: ['science1', 'science2'],
  sport: ['sport1', 'sport2'],
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#dropdown2, #dropdown3").hide();
  const optionString = buildOptions(product);
  $("#product").html(optionString);

  $("#product").change(function() {
    debugger;
    const selected = $("#product").val();
    const optinString = buildOptions(productDropDown1Relation[selected]);
    $('#dropdown2').html(optinString);
    $('#dropdown2').show();
  });

  $("#dropdown2").change(function() {
    const selected = $("#dropdown2").val();
    const optinString = buildOptions(dropDown1DropDown2Relation[selected]);
    $('#dropdown3').html(optinString);
    $('#dropdown3').show();
  });
});

function buildOptions(arr) {
  let optionString = `<option value=''>--Choose--</option>`;
  for (const element of arr) {
    optionString += `<option value='${element}'>${element}</option>`;
  }
  return optionString;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="product" name="faculty" required="">
</select>

<select id="dropdown2" name="dropdown2" required="">
</select>

<select id="dropdown3" name="dropdown3" required="">
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. And I still have a new question. If in the second list I add to the "Math" button a new list, where in the code will I have to add id = math?

Comment: If you want to open a new list when user selects math from second dropdow, then you have to create a new one like you have created third dropdown with id="math"

Comment: If it resolves your issue, can you please accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: It was already answered in the comments and the question should be closed as a typo-type question. Please read the comments before answering and consider if a question is worth answering

Comment: @JasdeepSingh, I made the list, but in the Javascript code, where did the id add? Thanks again

Comment: In fact I want when "Math" is displayed, the list with "info" is hidden.

Comment: @DariusPerta I have updated the code, we don't need to add much code as we are selecting the Id dynamically. So, When user is changing second dropdown, i am showing "math" or "info" dropdown based on value selected.

Comment: @mplungjan I think its always better to answer if another person is facing an issue unless its a duplicate issue. And its always good to answer with a working code.

Comment: And I did both in the comments under the question. It is a HUGE dupe - IDs MUST be unique. Remove the id from the select and this code would answer the original question `$("#1 select").on("change",function() { var selected = $(this).val(); $('p').hide(); $('#' + selected).show(); });`

Comment: @mplungjan can you please guide me how can i fix this. I am deleting my post, would request you to add the solution as per his requirement.

Comment: No. I wanted the question deleted. It does not matter now. You have answered TWO questions now - so never mind

Comment: @JasdeepSingh thank you again. The code works, but I would like to change the code a little so that when you select in the first list "id = 2" to open another list with a new list ("geography" and "history". For "geography" it is "geog1" and " geog2 "and for" history "is" hist1 "and" hist2 ". I can't do this: /

Comment: @DariusPerta As per your request, i have implemented it dynamically. Now dropdowns will populate dynamically depending upon the value selected in previous dropdowns. And its better approach than implementing large number of dropdowns in HTML. One request please create a new question if you have more requirements.

Comment: @JasdeepSingh thank you very much. The code works and it s all i need. Best regards!